# asymptotic behavior of the Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

We know, if the function $$f\in C^{k}(\Omega)$$ of one argument, than behavior of its members of the Fourier series is similar behavior of $\frac{1}{n^{k}}$, $n$ - number of member of the Fourier series.
My question is the following:
My function $u(t,x)$ is the function of two arguments $(t,x)$. $$u(t,x)=\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty} c_{k}(t) w_{k}(x),$$ where $c_{k}(t)=\int\limits_{\Omega} f(x,t)w_{k}(x)\,dx$.
What can we say about the behavior of $c_{k}(t)$???

Answer (score 1):

For each *fixed* $t$ you can apply the one-dimensional result to the function $x\mapsto u(t,x)$ and obtain some decay of $c_k(t)$ as $k\to\infty$. A precise statement to this effect is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318804). What you wrote in the post about $C^k(\Omega)$ does not look precise enough: if the Fourier series is of the usual exponential/trigonometric kind, then you need the *periodic extension* of $f$ to $\mathbb R$ to be $C^k$-smooth, not just $f$ itself. For example, $f(x)=x$ is very smooth on $(-\pi,\pi)$ but the Fourier expansion  $f(x)=\sum c_k \sin kx$ has $c_k\sim 1/k$.

If you want to know something about the behavior of $c_k(t)$ *as a function of* $t$, then you should say something about how $u(t,x)$ depends on $t$. Does it satisfy a PDE of some sort, maybe? Otherwise nothing can be said: $u(t,x)=  e^{e^t} \sin x$ is a very smooth function indeed, and the coefficient of $\sin x$ here can grow as fast as you wish.

Comment: The function must be considered as a periodic function. Therefore, $f(x)=x$ is a saw-tooth function which is not even $C^0$.