# Decay rate of Fourier coefficients of a continuous function with discontinuous derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis

Can you prove or disprove the following:

The Fourier coefficients of a continuous function with discontinuous derivative decay like $ 1/n^2$.

Comment: Doubtful. Take any discontinuous function with slow decay, i.e. $f(x) = \sum_k \frac{e^{ikx}}{\log k}$ (ptwise limit exists)  and integrate it (though not necessarily term by term)?  On the positive side, if the derivative is in $L^2$, then you have a positive result.

Comment: @Evan .Thank you for the answer.Let say $f'$ belongs to $L^2$.

Comment: Hmm.. I might be wrong about the decay rate actually.. But it's possible to prove that if $f'$ belongs to $L^2$ then the Fourier series converges uniformly. Would have to work it out again, but the idea is to use the fact that the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ are in $l^2$ and use Cauchy Schwarz on $\sum \frac{|a_k|}{k}$, which bounds the $l^1$ norm of the Fourier coefficients of $f$.

Comment: This is the Fourier transform version: [Relation between function discontinuities and Fourier transform at infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/318804/).

Comment: @user89499 thanks for the link.mm I went through the comments,however quite honestly didnt see a crisp proof or disprove for the Fourier transform version.Actually i used this statement somewhere and my advisor said: "its baloney".lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In stated generality this is false. Take  some periodic function with behaves like $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ near $0$. Since $f'(x)\notin L^2$, the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ are not in $\ell^2$.  In particular, they cannot decay like $1/n$.

The following  (adapted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318804/)) is true.

**Claim**. Suppose $f $ is piecewise differentiable, $f'$ has bounded variation on each "piece" $(a_k,a_{k+1})$ and   has nonzero jump discontinuity at some $a_k$.  Then the sequence $n^2\widehat f(n)$ is bounded but does not tend to $0$.

*Proof*: $n^2 \widehat f(n)$ has the same size as $\widehat \mu(n)$, where $\mu$ is the signed measure such that $f'=\int \,d\mu$. (That is, $\mu$ is the weak/distributional derivative of $f'$). By  the assumptions on $f'$, the measure $\mu$ consists of absolutely continuous component and some  point masses. The Fourier series for the absolutely continuous part has coefficients that tend to $0$, by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. The Fourier series for the sum of point masses is a trigonometric polynomial; therefore it is bounded but does *not* tend to $0$. $\quad \Box$

With some extra machinery, Claim can be generalized:

**Claim 2**. Suppose $f $ is absolutely continuous, $f'$ has bounded variation and is not continuous. Then the sequence $n^2\widehat f(n)$ is bounded but does not tend to $0$.

*Proof* goes as above, but the sticky point is to show that $\widehat \mu(n)\not\to 0$. A measure such that $\widehat \mu(n) \to 0$ is called a [Rajchman measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajchman_measure). From the survey [Seventy years of Rajchman measures](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/pdf/seventy.pdf) by Lyons we find that a Rajchman measure has no atoms (proved by Neder in 1920). But $f'$ is not continuous, which means the measure $\mu$ has atoms. $\quad \Box$

Comment: very interesting. The function in hand is $$\
Sqrt(x) Log(1+x)$$
. It seems to me it it of BV on [0,1]. because its derivative is integrable. Would you agree with me on that?

Comment: @BigM That is certainly true. Whether you have read my answer is less certain.

Comment: Updated Link to the "seventy years" paper: https://rdlyons.pages.iu.edu/#seventy