# The decay of Fourier coefficients and the continuity of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $ f $ be a function on $ \mathbb{T}=[0,1] $ ($ 1 $-periodic) with bounded variation. Prove that if $ \widehat{f}(k)=\int_0^1f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx=o(1/|k|) $, then $ f\in C(\mathbb{T}) $. I do not know how to use the assumption that $ f $ is of bounded variation. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: If $f$ has finite variance it means it has derivative (almost everywhere) and derivate is in $L^1$. Then integrate by parts and use the fact that Fourier coefficients of $L^1$ function tend to $0$. Maybe writing integral as a sum and using changing of order of summations would be simpler but this is the same idea.

Comment: Yes, $f'\in L^1$. But that integration by parts is not valid unless $f$ is absolutely continuous; here the relevant distribution-wise derivative of $f$ is a _measure_...

Comment: The last part of the following answer should be very helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467925/151552